# Regarding bullets and levelled bullets in ms word using c#

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word

I have a ribbon button which inserts numbered bullets in my doc like so:

```
private void button4_Click_1(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Word.ListGallery listGallery = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Application.ListGalleries[Word.WdListGalleryType.wdOutlineNumberGallery];
    oPara = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(range);
    listFormat = oPara.Range.ListFormat;
    this.ApplyListTemplate1(listGallery, listFormat, 1);
    range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = 1;
}
```

and I have another button which applies levelled numbered bullets like 1.1 ,1.2 etc like this

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Word.ListGallery listGallery = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Application.ListGalleries[Word.WdListGalleryType.wdOutlineNumberGallery];
    oPara = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(range);
    listFormat = oPara.Range.ListFormat;
    this.ApplyListTemplate1(listGallery, listFormat, 2);
    oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = 2;
 }
```

Here is my apply list template:

```
private void ApplyListTemplate1(Word.ListGallery listGallery, Word.ListFormat listFormat, int level = 2)
{
    listFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel(
    listGallery.ListTemplates[level],
    ContinuePreviousList: true,
    ApplyTo: Word.WdListApplyTo.wdListApplyToSelection,
    DefaultListBehavior: Word.WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior,
    ApplyLevel: level);
}
```

The problem:

Here if I click on the level 1 button it inserts a numbered bullet , like "1."  and I click on second button, it inserts "1.1.", and now if I press the first button to insert "2 ."  it inserts fine, but the second button click does not insert 2.1 ,instead it inserts "1.2" Have been stuck on it for days.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 
oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = 2; 
I used oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListIndent();
and oPara.Range.ListFormat.Outdent() instead of oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = 1; 
and it worked without bugs.